# Report doesn't sort by code

Tags: sorting, crystal-reports, vb6, report

I want to sort my using options of comboboxes. The report displays perfectly, except the sort is not working and throws no errors. I'm using Crystal Reports version 10.0.0.533 and Visual Basic 6

```
Dim Report  As New CRAXDRT.Report  
Set Report = App1.OpenReport(g_ReportDirectory & "xxxx.rpt")

If cmbRefresh6.Text <> "" Then

    Select Case cmbRefresh6.Text
                       Case "TestOne"
                      Report.RecordSortFields.Add Report.Database.Tables(2).Fields.Item(3), crDescendingOrder
                        Case "TestTwo"
                             Report.RecordSortFields.Add Report.Database.Tables(1).Fields.Item(23), crDescendingOrder
     End Select
End If

If (cmbRefresh1.Text <> "") Then
     Report.RecordSelectionFormula = "{WORK.ID}" = '1' 
End If
```

The application opens the report, show the data is unordered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution doing this. I created a group in my report and assigned to a formula field, the Report.Areas("GH3") refer to group header3 and Report.FormulaFields.Item(2) is my formula with the item to sort. 
I hope that helps you with similar problems having a second option to order.

```
If cmbRefresh6.Text <> "" Then

                    Select Case cmbRefresh6.Text
                        Case "TestOne"

                              Report.Areas("GH3").GroupConditionField = Report.FormulaFields.Item(3)
                              Report.Areas("GH3").SortDirection = crAscendingOrder
                        Case "TestTwo"

                              Report.Areas("GH3").GroupConditionField = Report.FormulaFields.Item(2)
                              Report.Areas("GH3").SortDirection = crAscendingOrder
                    End Select
                End If
```